# How can I set up a local LEP or LEMP stack as a web development environment?

Tags: web-development, php, lemp, nginx

How can I set up a simple, always-on development environment with PHP and Nginx, like the one configued in [elementary/mvp](https://github.com/elementary/mvp)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Step 1: Installation

The following commands both add repositories for the latest stack software, update and upgrade yourself, and then install the required system.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:nginx/stable &&
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/nginx &&
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6 &&
sudo apt-get update &&
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade &&
sudo apt-get install nginx php5-fpm php5-curl php5-geoip php5-json php5-mcrypt php5-memcache
```

Note: To turn this into a LEMP stack, just install [MariaDB](https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#distro=Ubuntu&distro_release=trusty--ubuntu_trusty) as if you were using Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty, and then `php5-mysql` and ass `phpmyadmin` to suit.

## Step 2: Configuration

`sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/sitename.conf`

Paste some configuration in, modifying the root, include and error_log paths.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name local.localtest.me;
    root /path/to/site;
    error_log /path/to/site_error.log;
    access_log off;
    autoindex on;
    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ @extensionless-php;
    }

    location @extensionless-php {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    }
}
```

You can test the configuration with Nginx.

`sudo nginx -t`

Now we just need to restart the service.

`sudo service nginx restart`

## Step 3: Use

Finally, navigate to [local.localtest.me](http://local.localtest.me/)

#### References:

1. https://github.com/elementary/mvp/blob/master/CONTRIBUTE.md